# Is $A$ similar to $A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Is $A$ similar to $A^T$? Where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix

Is this true? If so, we have to show there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that

> $A = P^{-1} A^T P$

How do I approach this?